# Rails Console Error... NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm testing my assocations in my models in rails. I'm on Rails 3.2, and ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
When I type "User.first" it works fine, returning the first user. When I type "Gear.first" it also works fine. However when I try to access gear through the user like "User.first.gears" I keep getting the following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant User::UserGear
from /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:119:in `compute_type'
from /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:172:in `klass'
from /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:385:in `block in source_reflection'
from /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:385:in `collect'
from /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:385:in `source_reflection'
from /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:508:in `check_validity!'
from /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:26:in `initialize'
from /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:24:in `initialize'
from /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_through_association.rb:10:in `initialize'
from /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/associations.rb:157:in `new'
from /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/associations.rb:157:in `association'
from /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:44:in `block in define_readers'
from (irb):2
from /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'1.9.3p0 :003 > exit
```

Here are my models
**User Class:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_secure_password
  has_many :gears, through: :user_gears
  has_many :user_gears
  before_save :create_remember_token

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :first_name,  presence: true,
                          length:  {:maximum => 50 }
  validates :last_name,  presence: true,
                         length:  {:maximum => 50 }
  validates :email,      presence: true,
                         format:  {:with => email_regex},
                         uniqueness:  {:case_sensitive => false}
  validates :password,   presence: true,
                         confirmation: true,
                         length: {within: 6..40}

  def name
   first_name + " " + last_name
  end

  private

    def create_remember_token
        self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

end
```

**Gears Class**

```
class Gear < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :size, :price, :image_url, :sub_category_id
  has_many :users, through: :user_gears
  has_many :user_gears
  belongs_to :sub_category

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :size,  presence: true
  validates :price, presence: true
  validates :sub_category_id, presence: true
end
```

**User_Gears Class**

```
class UserGears < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gear
  belongs_to :user
end
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to rename your `UserGears` class to `UserGear` and rename the file to `user_gear.rb`